# AngularJS - ng-disabled directive acting weird

Tags: angularjs

I'm using few modals in my angular project, in every modal which is a form I'm using button with `ng-disabled` directive and each modal has its own controller.

The issue is that when I debugging the code I can see that when I'm opening one modal the debugger run on all the `ng-disabled` directives in the code although it should run only on the `ng-disabled` function in the current modal that I use.

On each `ng-disabled` I run some verification function in its own controller,
like `ng-disabled='somefunction()'`
and `somefunction()` in the controller is `somefunction() = x || y;`

Do I miss something ?

controller:

```
app.controller('NewHolidayModalController', function ($scope, close, HolidaysService) {

var centerList = $scope.$parent.$$childHead.centers;
var currCenterDN = $scope.$parent.$$childHead.currentCenter.DN;
var indexOfCurrentCenter = _.indexOf(_.pluck(centerList, 'DN'), currCenterDN);
centerList[indexOfCurrentCenter].ticked = true;
var selectedDNs;
$scope.dt = k = new Date();
$scope.close = function (result) {
    centerList[indexOfCurrentCenter].ticked = false;
    close(result, 500); 
};
$scope.conditionsForSendNewHoliday = function () {
    selectedDNs = _.select(centerList, { ticked: true });
    return (($scope.starttime >= $scope.endtime) || ($scope.dt < k) || (angular.isDate($scope.dt) == false) || (angular.isDate($scope.starttime) == false) || (angular.isDate($scope.endtime) == false) || ($scope.HolidayName.length == 0) || (selectedDNs.length == 0));
};
$scope.addHoliday = function () {
    holiday = HolidaysService.formatDateAndTime($scope);
    for (i = 0; i < selectedDNs.length; i++)
        {
        newHoliday = { DN: selectedDNs[i].DN, HolidayName: $scope.HolidayName, HolidayDate: holiday.Date, BeginHour: holiday.start, EndHour: holiday.end }
            HolidaysService.addHoliday(newHoliday)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if ((_.select($scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays, { BeginHour: data.BeginHour }).length == 0) && (_.select($scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays, { EndHour: data.EndHour }).length == 0) && (_.select($scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays, { HolidayDate: data.HolidayDate }).length == 0) && (_.select($scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays, { EndHour: data.EndHour }).length == 0) && (_.select($scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays, { HolidayName: data.HolidayName }).length == 0))
                    $scope.$parent.$$childHead.holidays.push(data);
                centerList[indexOfCurrentCenter].ticked = false;
                alert("holiday was created");
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (status == 409)
                    alert("Holiday " + data.HolidayName + " Cannot be created for " + data.DN + " BECAUSE OF OVERLAPPED HOLIDAYS.")
            })
    }
}
```

})

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close(false)" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div isteven-multi-select
                                 input-model="$parent.$$childHead.centers"
                                 output-model="outputCenters"
                                 button-label="Name"
                                 item-label="Name (Route)"
                                 tick-property="ticked"
                                 max-labels="5" max-height="150px">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input ng-model="HolidayName" type="text" placeholder="Holiday Name" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                <p class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="$parent.dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
                            <timepicker-pop input-time="starttime" class="input-group"
                                            show-meridian='showMeridian'>
                            </timepicker-pop>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
                            <timepicker-pop input-time="endtime" class="input-group"
                                            show-meridian='showMeridian'>
                            </timepicker-pop>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close(false)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="addHoliday()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-disabled="conditionsForSendNewHoliday()">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I add the other controller and the html?

Comment: can you add some code example? better yet, can you create a plunkr with a demonstration of the problem?

Comment: Please add a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/) with a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly which modal directive or method you're using, but in my own experience with some of them, the controllers are initialized **before the DOM of the modal is loaded** so your function may not be behaving like intended.